# How should I create path on remote server and keep file on that server

Tags: ssh, scp, sftp

I have six Unix Server.
I have writen a script that returns directory and Used Memory of it  above certain threhold of that server.
This is essential for my team  on regular based monitoring for system disk checkup.

So on execution of myscript it will result a log file.
Log file conatin Max Value of directory above certain thresold.

Now my cocern is i want to execute this script on remaining 5 server for theire system disk checkup and that log will come to my orignal server (say Master)

So for performing this operation myscript must be present on other 6 servers.

So i am designing a script that will create a specfic path and keep myscript on that path.
After execution of script on all 5 servers they will resend respective log files to my original server(i.e Master)

Let me know ift its possible with **sftp -b mode**.
so batch file can able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your question is pretty vague I'm going to assume that you literally just want to make a file on one *nix box available on another *nix box.

The simplest way I can think yo do this would be to install sshfs (available in most distros using the default package manager, or via epel for RHEL.)

Without going into to much detail (all these steps should be google-able:

1. set up SSH keys from your workstation to the file host for your user account
2. Create the directory on the remote machine which you will want to use to store files
3. Install sshfs.

`apt-get install sshfs`

`yum install sshfs`

4. Mount the directory to a location you own locally. Ie.

`sshfs username@ remote.machine.com:/home/username/remotedir /home/localdir`

And you should be right to access the files as though they are local. There are a bunch of caveats you should probably check in

```
man sshfs
```

And

```
man fuse
```